# Color file size column based on size

Tags: 2013, document-library, client-side-rendering, large-file

Is there a possibility to color the File Size column in SharePoint 2013 with CSR? I want to color the column based on the actual file size.

e.g.
if the file is smaller than 10 MB then green,
if its between 10 and 30 mb yellow and when it's bigger than 30 mb red.

Maybe something like this? [this article](http://nearbaseline.com/2013/12/sharepoint-list-conditional-formatting-with-jslink/)

Regards Michael

Comment: https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/ another approach of calculated column in case its okay for your use

Answer (score 1):

- Add file size column to your view
- The Internal name of file size is `File_x0020_Size`
- Try to use this code at your JSLink with your condition based on `File Size`

> ```
>     Type.registerNamespace('CustomFormat');
>
>     CustomFormat.riskColor = function () {
>
>     var riskFieldsContext = {};
>     riskFieldsContext.Templates = {};
>     riskFieldsContext.Templates.Fields = {
>         "File_x0020_Size": { "View": CustomFormat.exposureColourTemplate }        
>     };
>
>     SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(riskFieldsContext);
>
>
>  }
>
>  // This function provides the rendering logic for list view
> CustomFormat.exposureColourTemplate = function(ctx) {
>   var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
>
>   if (parseFloat(fieldValue) < 10000) {
>       return "<span style='background-color : green'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> High (" + fieldValue + ")";
>   }
>   else if (parseFloat(fieldValue) >= 10000 && parseFloat(fieldValue) =<  30000) {
>       return "<span style='background-color : yellow'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Medium (" + fieldValue + ")";
>   }
>   else {
>       return "<span style='background-color : red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Low (" + fieldValue + ")";
>   }
> }
>
> //CSR-override for MDS disabled site 
> CustomFormat.riskColor();
>
> if (typeof _spPageContextInfo != "undefined" && _spPageContextInfo != null) {         
>   // CSR-override for MDS enabled site
>   RegisterModuleInit(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteCollectionDocuments/riskColor.js", CustomFormat.riskColor); 
> }
> ```

For more details check [client-side-rendering-2013](http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/client-side-rendering-2013/)